Split "Path Variable" string in a Dictionary in c#
I want to break the string:
value1/672/value2/32/value3/21413

In a
Dictionary<string, string>

How can I do this without the use for a for loop?

Because some values represent keys and some values represent values, a loop might be needed. Certainly, I don't see a problem using a loop here. Is there a particular reason why you want to avoid a for loop?

Assuming the provided string contains the first value as a key and the second is the value in the provided string
value1/672/value2/32/value3/21413

Here's how you can achieve the above:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "value1/672/value2/32/value3/21413";
        string[] parts = input.Split('/');
        var dictionary = parts
            .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
            .Where(x => x.index % 2 == 0) // Select only even indexed elements as keys
            .ToDictionary(x => x.value, x => parts[x.index + 1]); // Use the next element as value      
        
        foreach (var kvp in dictionary)   // Loop for printing the result only
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");   // Output the dictionary key and values
        }
    }
}


Refer to the working .netfiddle here


Toadd another approach, simple regex pattern will also work here:
just use pattern ([^/]+)/([^/]+) which uses:

(...) - capturing group
[^/]+ - match one or more (+ operator) character other from / (negated character class [^/]

This will match "pairs" of values delimited by /.
Here's C# code example:
var values = Regex
    .Matches(
        "value1/672/value2/32/value3/21413",
        "([^/]+)/([^/]+)")
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1], x => x.Groups[2]);


If you really want to you can do this with a couple LINQ operators but i don't see a lot of added value there :
var str = "value1/672/value2/32/value3/21413";

// Array containing [value1, 672, value2, 32, value3, 21413
var arr = str.Split('/');

arr
    // Zip gives you pairs between 2 collections, here i'm zipping arr with itself with first element skipped
    // this gives both the key => value but also the value=> key pairs
    // so this results in {value1, 672} which we want, but also in {672, value2} which we do not want
    .Zip(arr.Skip(1))
    // Keep only the even indexes to get rid of the pairs we don't want mentioned above
    .Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 0)
    // Convert those tuples to a dictionary
    .ToDictionary(item => item.First, item => item.Second);


I tried both your solution and SELA's. In your solution, the error occurs with .Zip(), which expects two parameters.

@UlissesFarias you may be using an older version of .net that doesn't have this overload, i copy/pasted the code here after testing it in linqpad, what version of .net are you targetting?

The version is 4.0.

@UlissesFarias i would recommend adding that tag when asking a question as 4.0 is ancient so you may be getting wrong answers assuming recent versions (.net 4.0 released 14 years ago)

should work using .Zip(arr.Skip(1),(First,Second)=> new {First,Second}) instead in .net 4.0
